# CSS changes not updating on site

Tags: css, symfony, caching, vagrant, assetic

Today I started changing some CSS on a Symfony (2.6) project. I added some styling to my newly created css file and everything was working fine. My problem occured when I went to add another style and nothing happened. I checked the dev window and couldn't find my styles anywhere. I've deleted the cache multiple times. Im using Symfony with a vagrant box. If I open the css file in the url it is filled with diamond/question marks and my first style entry is still there. I checked and the encoding is set to UTF-8. Ive never had issues like this with css, does anyone know what the problem could be?

I am using Assetic to include the style sheet within the project like this:

```
`<link href="{{ asset('css/print_production_report.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" />`
```

[image]

So to show you whats happening I'll start from the beginning. I had this stylesheet (ignore the error):

[image]

And upon checking the browser I still have:

[image]

Now when I add some random text or css to my stylesheet as so:

[image]

You will see that all my changes are being converted into these diamonds:

[image]

Comment: So I realized that each diamond is a change (character) that I have added to my stylesheet.

Comment: how do you include the css file to your page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue of caching files and replacing them with the unicode 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER' (�) has to do with sendfile. Turn sendfile/EnableSendfile off in nginx/apache.

Related question is here: [yeoman and angular utf8 issue and caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035444/yeoman-and-angular-utf8-issue-and-caching)

Comment: For future convenience SendFile is located in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Answer (score -1):

Insert

```
@charset "utf-8"
```

at the top of your file and make sure you've saved the file in UTF-8.
[Helpful link](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-charset)

Comment: and other inttteresting thing is - why IDE underlines name of your css file with red? It looks like there are some mistakes in the file

Comment: Alex those errors were because of random text I put in the css. I took my screenshots out of order. I tried @charset "UTF-8" and it did not work. I opened the file in notepad and checked to make sure it was also saved with UTF-* encoding.

Answer (score -1):

Takie this lower text and comment it, i mean use

> //comment blabla

In your css file.

Comment: That will not change anything. I tried adding regular css properties and the question marks still appear. I was just using the paragraph as content filler so you could see.